# i want to validate my code BUT messages does'nt show under username only shows under password i don't where i go wrong

Tags: html, jquery, css

I write a login form but I can't make it correctly in validation with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
      username: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5

      }
    },
    messages: {
      username: {
        required: "name is mandatory"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: arial;
  font-align: left;
}

body {
  font-family: calibri, arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: powderblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

span.password {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.login-form {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  position: relative;
  width: 390px;
  left: 35%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 6px solid#ff0000;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #00ffff;
}

.login-form h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 40px;
}

.login-form label {
  font-size: 29px;
  text-align: right margin:45px;
}

.login-form input[type=text],
.login-form input[type=password] {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.login-form button {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 79px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  padding: 8px 6px;
  border: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login-form button:hover {
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<div class="login-form">
  <h1>LOGIN PAGE</h1>
  <form action="#" name="form1" id="form1">

    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="username"><br>
    <br>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="pswd"><br>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox"  id= "remember" name="remember " value="remember me"> 
        <label for ="checkbox" name="checkbox" >Remember me</label>
        </span>
    <span class="password">Forget <a href="#" >Password ?</a></span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I've corrected the formatting of the code in your question, and placed it in an executable snippet. Please always ensure your code is at least readable before submitting your question.

Comment: Please comment on the answer as to why it does not answer your question instead of posting a new question where you paste everything in as a block quote

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, [HTML5 validation attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) could be used to validate

In the HTML snippet below **required**, **minlength**, **pattern** and **max** validation attributes were used.

```html
<form action="#" id="formOne" novalidate>
        <div class="FormGroup">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                class="FormGroup__Input"
                name="username"
                placeholder="username"
                data-v-input  
                minlength="6" 
                required
            />
            <span class="FormGroup__ErrorLabel"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="FormGroup">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input 
                type="number" 
                name="password"
                class="FormGroup__Input"
                placeholder="password"
                data-v-input
                minlength="5"
                required
            />
            <span class="FormGroup__ErrorLabel"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Steps to make this form work

1. put `novalidate` attribute on the form element to validate inputs using code (javascript).
2. Each input element should have a `name` attribute that should be unique to that input
3. Add `data-v-input` attribute to each input element you want to be considered for validation by the javascript.
4. Put your html5 validation rules on the input elements
5. To show errors, add an element just **below** the input element. **NOTE**: The error label should be the next sibling of the input field.

```js
'use strict';
const formNode = document.querySelector("#formOne");

initValidation(formNode, (form, data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
});

function initValidation(formNode, onSubmitHandler){
    const validationErrors = [];
    const inputs = formNode.querySelectorAll("[data-v-input]");
    const selects = formNode.querySelectorAll("[data-v-select]");

    formNode.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
    inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener("blur", handleBlur));
    inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener("input", handleInput));

    function handleSubmit(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        let formData = {};

        if(inputs.length > 0){
            inputs.forEach(input => {
                validateInput(input);
                formData[input.name] = input.value;
            });
        }
        if(selects.length > 0){
            selects.forEach(select => {
                validateInput(select);
                formData[select.name] = select.value;
            });
        }
        if(validationErrors.length === 0){
            formNode.reset();
            onSubmitHandler(formNode, formData);
        }
    }

    function handleBlur(evt){
        validateInput(evt.target);
    }

    function handleInput(evt){
        validateInput(evt.target);
    }

    function validateInput(inputNode){
        if(inputNode.validity.valid){
            let inputNodeIndex = validationErrors.indexOf(inputNode.name);
            validationErrors.splice(inputNode, 1);
            renderErrorLabel(inputNode, false);
        } else {
            validationErrors.push(inputNode.name);
            renderErrorLabel(inputNode);
        }
    }

    function renderErrorLabel(node, show = true){
        node.nextElementSibling.textContent = show ? node.validationMessage : "";
    }

    return true;
}
```

6. Copy the initValidation function into your javascript file.

To validate your form, evoke `initValidation` after DOM loads. It takes two arguments.

1. a form node: a result of `document.getElementById` or any of the DOM selectors. However, `initValidation` takes ***one*** form node.
2. a callback that receives the **form** node as it's first argument and the **form's data** as the second argument. Whatever you want to do after validation is complete goes in the body of that callback. **NOTE:** The callback is only called when all validations were passed and there's no error.